# Unable to get bottom padding between two section

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: g]

Unable to get bottom padding between the map and contact title .
I have tried all my best to add padding but I failed.

```
    <section class="map" id="map">
    <h2 class="title"> Vaccination Centre Near Me<center></h2>
    <div class="mapouter"><div class="gmap_canvas"><center><iframe width="1200" height="710" id="gmap_canvas" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=Thyrocare%20Patna&t=&z=13&ie=UTF8&iwloc=&output=embed" 
    frameborder="10" scrolling="no" marginheight="10" marginwidth="10"></iframe><a href="https://www.online-timer.net"></a><br><style>.mapouter{position:static;text-align:right;height:510px;width:1400px;padding-bottom:100px;}</style><a href="https://www.embedgooglemap.net"></a>
    <style>.gmap_canvas {overflow:hidden;background:none!important;height:710px;width:1400px;padding-left: 150px;padding-top: 10px;padding-bottom: 100px;padding-right: 150px;}
    </style>
    </div>
    </div>
    </section>

<!-- contact section start -->
<section class="contact" id="contact">
    <div class="max-width">
        <h2 class="title">Contact</h2>
        <div class="contact-content">
            <div class="column left">
                <div class="text">We will try our best to help you.</div>
                <p>We would try our best to help you in this tough times.</p>
                <div class="icons">
                    
                        
                    <div class="row">
                        <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i>
                        <div class="info">
                            <div class="head">Address</div>
                            <div class="sub-title">India</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Where's your CSS? Also your HTML code legible. There's no effort.

Comment: Css is imbedded in html only and I have not posted the whole code as this much is only required for the problem

Comment: Have you tried `margin-top` on `contact` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `margin-top` on `contact` div

```
<style>
   .contact {
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      margin-top: 60px;
   }
</style>
```